# Problema para executar "Update-Database"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, migrations

Estou seguindo o tutorial desse [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=2345&v=i9Il79a2uBU) para configurar um projeto ASP.NET MVC utilizando EntityFramework6. O banco utilizado no tutorial é SQLServer e o que estou tentando usar é o MySQL.

Já tenho o MySQL Connector instalado.

Consegui executar o comando "Enable-Migrations" (aos 39 min. do vídeo) porém estou com problema para executar "Update-Database -Verbose".

Segue o "cabeçalho" do erro:

`update-database -verbose
Using StartUp project 'ProjetoModeloDDD.MVC'.
Using NuGet project 'ProjetoModeloDDD.Infra.Data'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ProjetoModeloDDD.Infra.Data.Contexto.ProjetoModeloContext' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

A única referência que encontrei para "MySql.Data" está em App.Data que aparenta estar na versão 6.9.6.0, assim como o *assembly*:

`<DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o repositório do projeto:
https://github.com/feliupe/ProjetoDDD

Grato se alguém puder ajudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há diversas coisas erradas na sua configuração. Antes de trocar a tecnologia do banco, você deveria ter seguido o tutorial até o final. Vamos lá.

Em primeiro lugar, no seu arquivo `App.config`:

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Isto:

```
type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"
```

É do SQL Server, não do MySQL. O correto é, além de mudar a *factory*, especificar uma configuração não-padrão (ou o Entity Framework também vai tentar usar a configuração do SQL Server). Portanto:

Outra coisa é a configuração do *provider*:

```
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
```

É preciso definir a versão do Assembly aqui, ou corre o risco de o próprio MySQL usar uma versão errada.

```
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
            type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
</providers>
```

Ainda, a própria equipe do MySQL faz muita confusão com pacote. Tanto que você adicionou uma versão descontinuada da biblioteca de entidades. No seu `packages.config`:

```
<package id="MySQL.Data.Entities" version="6.8.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Não use este pacote `MySQL.Data.Entities`. Troque por `MySQL.Data.Entity`, no singular.

```
<package id="MySQL.Data.Entity" version="6.9.6" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Fiz mais algumas atualizações no seu projeto. Está tudo no *pull request* do GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Com a ajuda do Cigano o problema foi resolvido. Deixo aqui o que foi modificado no projeto, com base na resposta anterior e nas mudanças que ele fez.

### App.config (em Infra.Data)

Foi anterada a tag  com adição do atributo `codeConfigurationType` e mudança da tag `<defaultConnectionFactory>` para o correto, do MySql.

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
<defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
```

Foi adicionada também a versão do provider.

```
<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
        type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
```

### Package.csproj (em Infra.Data)

A configuração de pacotes ficou a seguinte:

```
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="MySql.Data" version="6.9.6" targetFramework="net45" /
<package id="MySQL.Data.Entity" version="6.9.6" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Ademais, as mesmas mudanças em `App.config` foram feitas em `Web.config` (na camada MVC) e assim pude executar o comando `Update-Database`.